# Adding new Ant targets to org.dita.eclipsehelp

Tags: ant, dita

I need to do some postprocessing with the output of Eclipse Help transformation. Nothing too fancy, just some folder arrangement, adding some extra files.
I made a plugin for this purpose, but I didn't find the right extension points for Eclipse help, so I've had to implement my ant targets with *depend.preprocess.post* and *depend.preprocess.clean-temp.pre*.

The result is obvious: my plugin is working, but messes up all other output type.

I think the best scenario for me would be an extension point right at the end of the Eclipse help pipeline. How can I achive something like that?

Currently using: DITA-OT 2.1

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see by opening the "DITA-OT/plugins/org.dita.eclipsehelp/plugin.xml", the "org.dita.eclipsehelp" plugin defines 4 extension points that could be used by another plugin, two of them are XSLT, one is for adding extra parameters and one called "dita.map.eclipse.index.pre" is for registering an extra ANT target to be called before the indexing is done.
So I think you will probably need to directly edit the "org.dita.eclipsehelp" plugin or copy it entirely and make it your own, rename its id, its transformation type.

Comment: I made my own customized copy of the plugin,  now everything works fine. Thanks for the quick response!